# MySQL 1111 - Invalid use of group function on use Min date

Tags: mysql

I need count number of accesses for single user for interval 10 days.

I see always the date of last access.

I have tried this query but it faults.

```
mysql> SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`theDate`), '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'First Access',
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(`theDate`), '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Last Access',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Number',
        TheUser
FROM
    `doTable`
WHERE
    `theDate` BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()),1)
AND DATE_SUB(MIN(`theDate`), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
GROUP BY
    TheUser
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC;
1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

If I use the date value the query worked.

```
mysql> SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`theDate`), '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'First Access',
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(`theDate`), '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Last Access',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Number',
        TheUser
FROM
    `doTable`
WHERE
    `theDate` BETWEEN '2015-01-01'
AND DATE_SUB('2015-01-22', INTERVAL 10 DAY)
GROUP BY
    TheUser
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Output:

```
+---------+------------+------------+--------+
| TheUser | First      | Last       | Number |
+---------+------------+------------+--------+
| s074    | 05/01/2015 | 05/01/2015 |     18 |
| x066    | 02/01/2015 | 12/01/2015 |     17 |
| f918    | 03/01/2015 | 03/01/2015 |     17 |
| l371    | 01/01/2015 | 02/01/2015 |     15 |
| b779    | 01/01/2015 | 02/01/2015 |     14 |
+---------+------------+------------+--------+
5 rows in set
```

**edit #1**

I have moved the condition on having clause, but the output is empty.

```
mysql> SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`theDate`), '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'First Access',
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(`theDate`), '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Last Access',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Number',
    TheUser,
    `DATA`
FROM
    `doTable`       
GROUP BY
    TheUser
HAVING
    'Number' > 1
AND `theDate` BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()),1)
AND DATE_SUB(MIN(`DATA`), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
ORDER BY
    'Number' DESC;
```

Comment: Unsure of it but User being a reserved word you should add backticks around it  in the Select and Group BY clauses. If you're looking for the mysql user, I've no idea. (showing your table schema could remove this last question)

Comment: I have changed in table schema User in TheUser, but I have the same error.

Comment: Move that comarison part to having clause, you cant have that in where clause.

Comment: According to [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) There's a couple of things to fix. Use your already calculated  `Number` alias instead of `count(*)` in having clause for exemple. (I'm not a mysql expert, so I may be wrong, trying to help :p)

Comment: Please see edit #1 in my initial question.

Comment: I would request you to provide some sample data and if possible into the http://www.sqlfiddle.com